# Splash Screen synchronized loading

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-canvas, splash-screen

I have implemented a loading screen (splashScreen) but want it to synchronize it with my actual app loading. I want the app to load the main page in the background so when it is done with the timed load on my loading screen, it will already have the main screen pulled up in the background. I am relatively new to Async task and threads since I don't do much apps with games but could use some help with this. Thanks

Canvas Load Bar movement:

```
public class CustomRectangle extends View{

float left = 0, right = 500, top = 500, bot = 1000;
boolean check = false, finish = false;
int screenWidth = 0, screenHeight = 0;
Bitmap image;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
public CustomRectangle(Context context){
    super(context);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    this.screenHeight = size.y;
    this.screenWidth = size.x;

    this.image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    this.image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this.image, screenWidth, screenHeight, false);

}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(check == false) {
        Paint paintInitial = new Paint();
        paintInitial.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        this.left = 0;
        this.top = canvas.getHeight() - 10;
        this.right = canvas.getWidth();
        this.bot = canvas.getHeight();
        canvas.drawRect(left, top - 10, right, bot, paintInitial);
        this.check = true;
    }
    if(check == true && finish == false) {
        Paint paintWhite = new Paint();
        paintWhite.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint paintYellow = new Paint();
        paintYellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bot, paintYellow);
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
        top = top - 5;
        invalidate();
        if(top <= 0){
            finish = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Home_Page.class);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
            Log.e("", "Finished Loading!");

        }
    }
}
```

}

Splash Screen Activity:

```
public class SplashScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

Rect loadBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new CustomRectangle(this));


}
```

}

As of now, the bar loads up to the top of the screen and then starts the main activity but I don't think the main screen loads til the end so this doesn't actually load synchronously. If someone could lead me in the right direction to examples or post a revised code, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what it is that you have done, but if you just need a loading bar, what I would suggest is to have just the one activity. In the layout file, make it a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout. Inside, you can have your progress bar, and another layout with your main activity layout. Make the main activity layout invisible to start with, and both should have their width/height to match_parent.

When your activity starts up, it will only be showing the progress bar, then once you have finished loading, you can simply set the progress bar to invisible, and your main layout to visible.

One thing to be careful of is to make sure that when you change the visibility of your Views to run it on the UI thread. You can do this by calling the runOnUiThread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: I am not running a typical progress bar. I am using a rectangle as the loading bar which fill the screen and i am putting an image in front of the rectangle so the image looks like the progress bar. The rectangle increases in height every second until it hits the top of the screen and then starts the activity. I am using a canvas to draw a rectangle as my progress bar. This helps though so thanks. Unless you can get a progress bar to fill the whole screen, then I will stick to my code as I have it

Comment: Certainly you don't have to use an actual progress bar, the approach will work with any custom design you want to use to show the progress.